# Setting up webserver with ISPConfig : mail configuration

Tags: 12.04, server, mail, mail-server

I have installed my Ubuntu 12.04 web server following the [guide available on how to forge](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3).
Then, I have created one client in ISPConfig. Using this client, I have a domain (example.com) and a mailbox (client@example.com) in the e-mail configuration of ISPConfig.

I do not use any DNS system on my server (though Bind has been installed by the procedure) and I have setup my registrar's DNS (OVH) for the domain as follow :

```
.example.com      NS      Their main server name
.example.com      NS      Their secondary server name
.example.com      MX 1    example.com
.example.com      MX 100  example.com
.example.com      A       MY_SERVER_IP
www.example.com   A       MY_SERVER_IP
mail.example.com  CNAME   example.com
smtp.example.com  CNAME   example.com
```

I can see the mailbox using the webmail, but :

– I can't use it to send mails (composing a new mail and hitting send doesn't do anything)
– When I send mails to client@example.com, the webmail doesn't report anything in the inbox.

When I try to setup the mailbox (IMAP) using a client (Apple mail) I can go through the IMAP setup (apparently, mail is able to contact the server mail.example.com and log in) but I can't setup the SMTP on smtp.example.com or on mail.example.com or on example.com. The request times out.

**What's wrong with my setup ?**

[Here are the latest mail logs](http://pastebin.com/u86dRStM).

I have replaced my domain by example.com and the IP address from my router at home by MY_HOME_IPV4_ADDRESS. That's probably either attempts from Apple mail to check smtp and imap for the mailbox I tried to configure, or to send an e-mail towards client@example.com.

Remark: Of course, my server is configured with the real domain name, not with example.com

Comment: Your mail problem might be in your postfix configuration. Try editing `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and set the `mydestination` value to `$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost` Also worth reading is the [Postfix SASL HowTo](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) as it seems that your auth attempts are not being passed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found the solution to this issue. I had commented out the line `submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, uncomment the lines:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd

[...]

smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: Uncomment them from where?

Comment: Good point @Oli.